# FInd nearer location's lat long?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app in which I want to send SMS of my location with navigation link to the people around me who has my app installed.
how can I get the lat-long nearer to me who has my app installed and how can I send SMS of my location to them??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

1. Send a message to your server telling it that you want to broadcast to all devices. This message should include who you are and your location coordinates. You can use  [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) - the other devices need to be registered first on your server before they are able to receive the message.
2. These devices will reply back to the server, I suggest via a background service, their coordinates.
   The server needs to remember who did the request and its coordinates. Then apply Pythagorean theorem on each of the replies to determine which one is the nearest to the sender.
3. Send back the identity of the nearest device to the one who made the original request. This of course includes the coordinates of that device.

Make sure to add a timeout on Step 2. After X seconds, any device who hasn't replied should not be waited upon.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I have applied it and it will be done soon.

Answer (score 0):

i am not cleard a much but suggations are ther on the basis what i understand from the question
1) if the devices are very near to you than with the bluetooth can work
2) if the devices support NFC , we can take help to send and receive data
3) wifi- p2p(peer to peer) if the devices are sharing same internet connection

Comment: i just want to send my location via sms to the people around me.and this sms will be sent whenever a particular activity run in my app like pressing a button or shaking the mobile..is it possible to send my location to the people around me near by 1 or 2 km by google or android maps api??